# Spring hibernate gives errors after deleted column

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have created a springboot application with some columns.Table has been created properly.After that, I deleted surname column from database and from my Student.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT)
public class StudentEntity {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 10)
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname", length = 10)
private String surname;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "MASTER_ID")
private StudentEntity masterId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER)
private List<StudentEntity> detailTransactions = new ArrayList<>();

public Staff() {
}
```

After deleted,

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 10)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "MASTER_ID")
private StudentEntity masterId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER)
private List<StudentEntity> detailTransactions = new ArrayList<>();

public Staff() {
}
```

Now, I get some errors when i want to execute findAll method.

My error is : `could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`.Do you have any idea? How to update hibernate?

My application.properties file is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=false
```

Comment: If the application starts then JPA is fine with the data model, I suggest to enable SQL (`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true`, then post more logs about the error and maybe the DAO code

Comment: Do you have more attributes/associations in class Staff? If yes post the code

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Application is starting but when i want to execute for example findAll method , I get Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet and Hibernate:  `select student0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, student0_.NAME as NAME1_0_0_ ,left outer join detailTran1 ,detailtran1_.ID as ID1_0_2_, detailtran1_.NAME as NAME3_0_2_, detailtran1_.SURNAME as SURNAME18_0_2_ where student0.ID=?`

Comment: I think detailTransaction is still contains surname attribute

Comment: I think your issue is the MASTER_ID and masterId. One of these two are incorrect. You can check if you have MASTER_ID or masterId in your joining table as a foreign key.